# Cant find solution for Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Tags: php, html

I have this code and in the `ELSE`  it gives me this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)` and when i count the `{}` there are look fine.
Can you help me please to solve that problem?
Thank you

```
function showProfile($username)
{
    if (file_exists("$username.jpg"))
        echo "<img src='$username.jpg' align='left' />";

    $result = queryMysql("SELECT fname,lname,gender,age,disease,spid FROM patient WHERE username='$username' UNION SELECT fname,lname,gender,age,specialty,doctorID FROM doctor WHERE username='$username'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo stripslashes($row[0]) . "<br/>";
        echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=left /><br />Gender: ";
        echo stripslashes($row[2]) . "<br clear=left /><br />Age: ";

        if("SELECT username FROM patient WHERE username='$username'");
        {
            echo stripslashes($row[3]) . "<br clear=left /><br />Disease: ";
            echo stripslashes($row[4]) . "<br clear=left /><br />SPID: ";
            echo stripslashes($row[5]) . "<br clear=left /><br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo stripslashes($row[3]) . "<br clear=left /><br />Specialty: ";
            echo stripslashes($row[4]) . "<br clear=left /><br />Doctor ID: ";
            echo stripslashes($row[5]) . "<br clear=left /><br />"; 
        }

    }
}
```

PS: I searched for same problems in the site but i couldnt

Comment: You have an extra `;` after your innermost `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a `;` after your if, remove it, and you'll be good

```
if("SELECT username FROM patient WHERE username='$username'");
```

should be

```
if("SELECT username FROM patient WHERE username='$username'")
```

It helps if you put your braces `{` on the same lines